# What is aptitude"upgrade" failing here while apt-get succeeds?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt, aptitude

**UPDATE:**
added `why-not` output as suggested (`why` output also).

```
# aptitude why-not libwbclient0
Unable to find a reason to remove libwbclient0.`  `why` gives this reasoning. 


# aptitude why libwbclient0
i   nagios-plugins-standard Recommends smbclient                                     
p   smbclient               Depends    samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.11)
p   samba-libs              Depends    libwbclient0 (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
```

Why is `aptitude upgrade` failing to actually upgrade the package here while `apt-get upgrade` is willing to perform? As I understand, these two commands should be functionally the same but obviously they disagree. Can anyone explain how to find the problem here and why it works for one command but not the other?

**aptitude**

```
# aptitude upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

**apt-get**

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwbclient0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Running `aptitude why-not libwbclient0` should give you a clue as to why it's not installing.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, not much info given. Question updated with output.